# Where should "registerForRemoteNotifications" be called ? iOS8 vs iOS9 seems to be behaving differently based on where this method is called

Tags: ios9

There seems to be some differences in iOS9 vs iOS8 with regards to calling "registerForRemoteNotifications" and generating a push token.

In iOS8 calling "registerForRemoteNotifications" inside the method "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" works fine and push tokens are generated.

But in iOS9 calling "registerForRemoteNotifications" inside "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" does not work and no push token is generated. Instead if I wait for the callback "didRegisterUserNotificationSettings" to trigger and then call "registerForRemoteNotifications" inside that method then push tokens are generated fine.

NOTE : "didRegisterUserNotificationSettings" is called when the user accepts the notification permissions.

Apple's documentation recommends calling "registerForRemoteNotifications" inside "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions". Look at "Listing 2-4" under the following link,
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html

There is no apple documentation that I can find that says calling "registerForRemoteNotifications" before the callback "didRegisterUserNotificationSettings" is not advised.

Anyone else facing similar issues with iOS9 vs iOS8 behavior ?